# How to add a css reference within a server control?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, css

I've built a custom server control that uses custom CSS. The problem that I have is that I have to set a reference to the css file on each page I use the control.

Can I set this reference inside the control ? So that I could just add the control and not worry about the reference.

Answer (score 14):

You need to follow the below steps to add the css/javascript/image in the web control itself.

1. Modify the AssemblyInfo.cs file, to add the web resource

   [assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("CustomControls.Styles.GridStyles.css", "text/css"), PerformSubstitution = true)]
2. Adding the required files(css/javascript/images) to the custom server control solution. Note that we can add folders in the solution and just add separate it using '.'(dot)
3. More importantly, we should change the BuildAction Property from Content to Embedded Resource of the newly added css/javascript/image files.
4. Further we should load the stored resources from the DLL. Best event for this would be OnPreRender
   Below is the sample code rendering css

   ```
   protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) 
      {
           bool linkIncluded = false;
           foreach (Control c in Page.Header.Controls)
           {
               if (c.ID == "GridStyle")
               {
                   linkIncluded = true;
               }
           }
           if (!linkIncluded)
           {
               HtmlGenericControl csslink = new HtmlGenericControl("link");
               csslink.ID = "GridStyle";
               csslink.Attributes.Add("href", Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "CustomControls.Styles.GridStyles.css"));
               csslink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
               csslink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
               Page.Header.Controls.Add(csslink);
           }
       }
   ```

Similarly for Adding javascript

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        string resourceName = "CustomControls.GridViewScript.js";
        ClientScriptManager cs = this.Page.ClientScript;
        cs.RegisterClientScriptResource(this.GetType(), resourceName);
    }
```

Similarly using the Added Image in CSS file. Use the below code

```
background: url('<%=WebResource("CustomControls.Styles.Cross.png")%>') no-repeat 95% 50%;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here what I use to add css reference to Page programmatically :

```
HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();
link.Href = relativePath;
link.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
link.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);
```

Maybe you should add some code to check if the css file added to the header control.

Comment: Where should I embeed this in the custom server control ?

Comment: In which phase of the creation cycle ?

Comment: CreateChildControls is suitable, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you want build webcontrol, that will be reusable and in one assembly with css, js and other resources, than you can use WebResources

[Working with Web Resources in ASP.NET 2.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910442)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) - and this will also help you embed the stylesheet in the custom control library's DLL.

Or you could just reference the CSS from your master page. Unless you're packging a custom control library to sell etc, ScriptManager is a LOT of extra effort vs the Master Page solution

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could add [Canavar's code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1366553/496830) to a base class that would be included with all the classes that need it.

```
public class myclass : BaseClass
{
    var customCSS = customcss();
     Page.Header.Controls.Add(customCSS); }
```

and your baseclass:

```
public class BaseClass : Page
{
    public HtnlLink customcss(){
        HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();
    link.Href = relativePath;
    link.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
    link.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
    return link;
}
}
```

or you could go down the route of

```
myObject.Attributes.Add("style","width:10px; height:100px;");
```

or

```
myObject.Attributes.Add("style",customStyle(););
```

where this is in your baseclass

```
public String customStyle()
{
return "width:10px; height:20px;";
}
```

and `customstyle` would be a function like so:

But I would assume that you use CSS for the rest of your site, so maybe a style could just be added to your stylesheet that you use on all pages through this method you could use the below code:

```
myObject.Attributes.Add("class","customControl");
```

This will then reference the correct CSS style from your main, always included stylesheet.

Unless I am missing something here....